# Unable to mount using mount.cifs command

Tags: mount, cifs

I am trying to mount using:

```
mount.cifs //ad.xxx.py/home/yyyyy /mnt/adhome –o user=yyy
```

after entering the password I get:

> mount error(13): Permission denied
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Can someone explain what is going wrong here?

Comment: are you running the mount.cifs command as a non-root user (who might not have permission to mount to /mnt/adhome), or as root?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the share permission.

If it is an 'open share' use the `-o username=username -o rw -o noperm` switches

I use this on a 'open' samba share:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ls3/share /mnt/share -o username=username -o rw -o noperm
```

If it is not a 'open' share try:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ls2/share /mnt/ls2 -o username=user -o password=userPW
```

Or use a credentials file:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ls2/share /mnt/ls2 -o credentials=/path/cred_file
```

see

```
man mount.cifs
```